# cannot get / when opening project

Tags: angular, typescript

i am facing this weird bug - When i close and reopen my project in Webstorm IDE and then launch the project i get cannot get/ error. This error gets resolved if i delete route
{path: '', component: AppComponent}, and then the app works as it should. If i again save and close my project and then reopen again, the same error reoccurs, but now if i include the same path i deleted in the previous session {path: '', component: AppComponent} in the routes again, The project works just fine. And again if i save and close my project and reopen again, i'll get the error again and now this time again deleting the route fixes the problem. So i am stuck in this vicious cycle where i have to delete/include route according to the situation everytime i open my project. please help.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './Navbar/Navbar.component';
import { ArraysComponentComponent } from './arrays-component/arrays-component.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { StackComponent } from './stack/stack.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { QueueComponent } from './queue/queue.component';
import { CircularQueueComponent } from './circular-queue/circular-queue.component';
import { CarouselComponent } from './carousel/carousel.component';
import { LinkedListComponent } from './linked-list/linked-list.component';
import { HomeContentsComponent } from './home-contents/home-contents.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ParticlesModule} from 'angular-particle';
import '@angular/compiler';
import { BackgroundComponent } from './background/background.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {FirebaseService} from './services/firebase.service';
import { BubbleSortComponent } from './SortingTechniques/bubble-sort/bubble-sort.component';
import { InsertionSortComponent } from './SortingTechniques/insertion-sort/insertion-sort.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // {path: '', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'arrays', component: ArraysComponentComponent},
  {path: 'stack', component: StackComponent },
  {path: 'queue', component: QueueComponent },
  {path: 'bubbleSort', component: BubbleSortComponent},
  {path: 'insertionSort', component: InsertionSortComponent},
  {path: 'll', component: LinkedListComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ArraysComponentComponent,
    StackComponent,
    QueueComponent,
    CircularQueueComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
    LinkedListComponent,
    HomeContentsComponent,
    BackgroundComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    BubbleSortComponent,
    InsertionSortComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ParticlesModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyAcFmdpNWPHs22gRXwoLlO8QQdcPkKwQtM',
      authDomain: 'dsalgo-210c7.firebaseapp.com',
      projectId: 'dsalgo-210c7',
      storageBucket: 'dsalgo-210c7.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '904101204684',
      appId: '1:904101204684:web:d001f5647d004f0140e869',
      measurementId: 'G-962JE081HH'
    }),
  ],
  providers: [FirebaseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You don't have to specify AppComponent in the routes since it's route of application

Answer (score 0):

The issue you got is that Angular at first shows you some errors, on any (!) change in some file it recompiles and uses cached data for it, thus the issue seems to be gone away.
[The documentation doesn't state that](https://angular.io/cli/serve), but it's my long-years experience that Angular behaves this way.

That's not the case, the compiler still has this issue as the console-output should clearly show, nevertheless you can open the browser without any error.

Regarding the "AppComponent" in the path @Yuriy is right with the comment that AppComponent doesn't need to be in the Routes. You always habe one static "Root Component" - that is the AppComponent. The Routes listed are rendered in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` you have anywhere in your app. Since the Appcomponent holds this RouterRoutlet, you should not display the AppComponent in there.
For more Details on Routing see [Angulars Guide on that](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Show us your console-output for more details on that (maybe a recursion or non-unique outlet).

Comment: The console shows this error-
GET http://localhost:4200/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I mean the bash or powershell, whatever you started the angular-cli command with. It should contain more details, the message you're giving us seems to be from the browser's console, may that be the case?
If you delete the AppComponent from the Routes, the error still occurs right after restart?